# Sitecore Coveo Lost connection to RabbitMQ after rebuild

Tags: sitecore, coveo

I have basic setup of coveo and guest connection to RabbitMQ on local host,
but when I rebuild sitecore solution Coveo lost connection to RabbitMQ,
I need manually connect via Indexing Queue Connection menu.

```
   <!-- Coveo search configuration -->
          <SearchCertificatePath>C:\CES7\Config\Certificates\cert-iis.p12</SearchCertificatePath>
          <SearchServiceUri>https://localhost:52810/7.0/CoveoSearchService</SearchServiceUri>
          <QueueUri>amqp://localhost:5682/</QueueUri>
          <QueueUsername>guest</QueueUsername>
          <EncryptDataOnQueue>false</EncryptDataOnQueue>
```

how to store passwords as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question needs a little bit of clarification so I'll give answer for multiple things.

First, it's not clear where you trigger the rebuild operation. Is it from the Sitecore Indexing Manager or from the Coveo Enterprise Search Administration Tool on a Queue source? The rebuild operation should always be triggered from the Sitecore Indexing Manager. Triggering a rebuild on a Queue source in the CES Admin Tool is useless because it just closes the read connection to RabbitMQ and reopens it.

You mention that Coveo lost connection to RabbitMQ. Is it CES that lost connection to read the queued messages or Sitecore that lost the connection to send messages to RabbitMQ or both? At each Sitecore indexing operation (rebuild index, item added, item modified, item deleted, publish...), Coveo for Sitecore first updates the CES sources with the QueueUri, QueueUsername and QueuePassword stored in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file. If the CES sources configuration did change, the read connections to RabbitMQ are closed and reopened. Then, Coveo for Sitecore connects to RabbitMQ and pushes the indexing messages.

You mention that you have to set the Queue uri, username and password again from the Indexing Queue Connection Configuration Wizard. What are the values of the QueueUri, QueueUsername and QueuePassword elements before you do that operation? Are they already correct or are they reset to their default values or wrong values? It may indicate a problem in your deployment processes. Maybe the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file is overwritten periodically with wrong values for those elements.

Lastly, Coveo for Sitecore stores the Queue and Sitecore passwords in an encrypted form directly in the QueuePassword and SitecorePassword elements of the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file. The passwords are encrypted with a key that is generated in your Sitecore instance `\Data\Coveo\ConfigurationEncryptionKeys` folder. You should check the existence of the `RijndaelEncryptionKeys` file in that folder.

If you moved the Coveo for Sitecore configurations to another config file, the Sitecore control panel configuration wizards like the Indexing Queue Connection Configuration Wizard won't be able to write the new values to your custom configuration file.

I hope this answers your question and resolves your problem.

Jeff

Comment: I have local sitecore instance that working with local Coveo instance, it seam working well, but when I make deploy (and yes config file is replaced via deploy) Inside of coveo diagnostic page in sitecore I see that RabbitMQ connection is in red light. I am goint to  Sitecore Indexing Manager inside of sitecore and set up guest password and login, and RabbitMQ back to live (green light). I just want to undestend why connection is closed after rebuild, and how store password for case if password should be in Coveo.SearchProvider.config

Comment: RijndaelEncryptionKeys exist but how it could help ?

Comment: Your connection isn't reset on the rebuild operation. It is reset when you deploy your `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file with invalid queue uri, username and password over the working one.

You should take a copy of the values of the QueueUri, QueueUsername and QueuePassword elements of your config after you set them using the Indexing Queue Connection Configuration Wizard. Then put those values in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file in your source control. Then, the next time this file will be deployed, it will have the valid values and your connection won't be reset.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I did it, I added it to config file like on my question body, <QueueUri>amqp://localhost:5682/</QueueUri>          <QueueUsername>guest</QueueUsername> <QueuePassword>guest</QueuePassword> and after rebuild connection is lost.  Coveo.SearchProvider.config file looks fine under web site... I don't know why connection is lost. but it start work fine after manual update. May be the key answer in RijndaelEncryptionKeys file...

Comment: Is it possible that you are also deleting or overwriting the `RijndaelEncryptionKeys` file on deploy? This file is used to write and read the encrypted passwords. If the file is not present on the file system, a new one will be generated when a password needs to be read or written. After the use of the Indexing Queue Connection Configuration Wizard to fix the connection problem, I suggest you to copy the `RijndaelEncryptionKeys` file in your source control and to deploy this file each time you deploy the configuration files.

Comment: I do not replace this file during build, may be if Coveo.SearchProvider.config changed or IIS reload this file get not valid state or something like this

Comment: This file is not present by default when you install Coveo for Sitecore. It is created only when the first password needs to be written or read. You should follow my recommendation and put it in your source control and deploy it.

Comment: To be honest I don't see the any reason for it, i see that this file was created during coveo sitecore package installation, and never  changed after it (I guess it contains encrypted 'guest' password). How it help if I just replace it ?

Comment: The `RijndaelEncryptionKeys` contains an encryption key used to encrypt the various passwords kept in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.config` file. Cna I ask you which releases of Sitecore, Coveo Enterprise Search, and Coveo for Sitecore you are using? Complete version numbers with major, minor and build/release/update numbers please. Thanks